# Ultimo header de section tiene un formato diferente

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estoy haciendo una pequeña practica en SwiftUI tengo tres `Sections` el ultimo muestra el `header` de manera diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                    Section(header: Text("¿Cuando quieres levantarte ?")) {
                                                       DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                                                       .labelsHidden()
                                                          .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                    }
                    Section(header: Text("Horas de sueño deseadas ")){
                        Stepper(value: $sleepAmount, in: 4.0...12.0, step: 0.25){
                            Text("\(sleepAmount, specifier: "%g") hours")
                        }
                    }
                    Section(header: Text("Tazas de cafe al dia ☕️")){
                        Stepper(value: $coffeeAmount, in: 1...20){
                            if coffeeAmount == 1 {
                                Text("1 taza ☕️")
                            } else {
                                Text("\(coffeeAmount) tazas ☕️")
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    Section(header: Text("Solo una prueba a ver si con mas texto algo cambia")){
                            Text("Hola")
                    }
                     .navigationBarTitle("Dulces Sueños ")
                     .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: calculateBedtime) {
                        Text("Calcular")
                     })
                    .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                                Alert(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text(alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) )
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    static var defaultWakeTime: Date {
        var components =  DateComponents()
        components.hour = 7
        components.minute = 0
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components) ?? Date()
    }
    func calculateBedtime() {
        let model = SleepCalculator()

        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: wakeUp)

        let hour = (components.hour ?? 0) * 60 * 60
        let minutes = (components.minute ?? 0) * 60

        do {
            let predicttion =  try model.prediction(wake: Double(hour + minutes), estimatedSleep: sleepAmount, coffee: Double(coffeeAmount))

            let SleepTime = wakeUp - predicttion.actualSleep

            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.timeStyle = .short

            alertMessage = formatter.string(from: SleepTime)
            alertTitle = "Tu hora ideal para dormir es..."
        } catch{
            alertTitle = "Error"
            alertMessage = "Perdon, algo salio mal"
        }

        showingAlert = true

    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué el ultimo se muestra diferente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el error fue poner el `.navigationBarTitle` dentro del `form`

```
                     .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: calculateBedtime) {
                        Text("Calcular")
                     })
```

al ponerlo fuera todo funciono normal de nuevo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]